# A deck of poker cards as dice

Tags: dice, playing-cards

What resource do you use for online play when it comes to drawing a playing card in addition to rolling a dice?

If it is only about drawing 1/54 (pack of cards + 2 jokers) card where the result is
red/black or value 9+ or a joker. Can this also be displayed with different dice?

Answer (score 8):

### Roll20 has a feature just for that

You can use the [Cards](https://wiki.roll20.net/Cards) feature on Roll20. As per the documentation:

> Card Decks in Roll20 are Collections (e.g. a deck) of one or more card objects that can be shuffled, drawn, dealt to players, traded between players, and can be played directly to the Tabletop. by default on the Collections-tab

[image]

Alternatively, you can just use a command like

> /roll d54

with a predefined mapping table of results to cards, as roll20 is not limited to using dice that can be created physically.

If you used the order that is [used on the print sheets](https://www.quora.com/Why-does-a-straight-deck-of-cards-have-two-jokers) for cards in western reading sequence, 1 and 2 would be the jokers, followed A to 10, J, Q, K of Spades, A to 10, J, Q, K of Diamonds, K, Q, J, 10 to A of Clubs, and K, Q, J, 10 to A of Hearts, (the two kings in the middle are traditionally called the "Kissing Kings"), but of course you can really use whatever order or mapping you like.